# Java-Swing: Can't trap user into typing a correct filename

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to trap a user into typing a correct file name unless he presses cancel or X. But if he does cancel the input my program throws a NullPointerException.

```
public void openSaveAsDirectory() {

    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Save file as");
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(adTable, "Please type a name for your file");
    if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {

        File fileName = new File(SAVE_LOCATION + FILE_SEPERATOR + name + FILE_SUFFIX);
        book.saveUser(fileName);

    }

    while(name.isEmpty()) {
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(adTable, "Please type a name for your file");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if they cancel your input dialog, `name` will be null. You do `while (name.isEmpty()) {`. `name` could be null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Just curious: why are you using JOptionPane vs. JFileChooser?

Comment: @ControlAltDel no real reason. would it be better to use JFileChooser?

Comment: @nbokmans Possibly a stupid question but if a user cancels the dialog and name is null would't it just do nothing?

Comment: @lucas6198 JFileChooser would definitely get you a file. Getting a file from a file path that the user provided is not safe to always return a valid file.

Comment: @lucas6198 If name is null, then you try to evaluate null.isEmpty(). That's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, here is an updated version that asks for an input as long as it is empty but stops, when the user hits the cancel button.

```
String name;
do {
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please type a name for your file");
    if(name == null) { //user hit cancel, break the loop
        break;
    }
} while(name.isEmpty());
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just trap a user forever? Because while name==null only occurs if the user presses cancel or X if I'm not mistaken. But I want the user to be able to cancel the input.

Comment: Correct, that would keep asking forever. You never stated that you want it to stop, when the user cancels (although it makes perfect sense!).

Comment: My fault I'm not good at expressing myself in english :/ I want him to be able to cancel the input.